# Qt && CMake - Could not find a configuration file for package "Qt6" that is compatible with requested version ""

Tags: qt, cmake, clion

I'm building a project using Qt6.6.0 and CMake, and an error occurs:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package "Qt6" that is compatible
  with requested version "".

  The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

    D:/Qt6/6.6.0/mingw_64/lib/cmake/Qt6/Qt6Config.cmake, version: 6.6.0 (64bit)
```

I've checked that file  `D:/Qt6/6.6.0/mingw_64/lib/cmake/Qt6/Qt6Config.cmake` exists.
Although I've set my `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, this error is not been cleared.
Here is my CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(untitled2)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "D:/Qt6/6.6.0/mingw_64/lib/cmake")

set(QT_VERSION 6.6.0)

find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS
        Core
        Gui
        Widgets
        REQUIRED)

add_executable(untitled2 main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(untitled2
        Qt::Core
        Qt::Gui
        Qt::Widgets
        )

if (WIN32 AND NOT DEFINED CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE)
    if (MSVC AND CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES "Debug")
        set(DEBUG_SUFFIX "d")
    endif ()
    set(QT_INSTALL_PATH "${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}")
    if (NOT EXISTS "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/bin")
        set(QT_INSTALL_PATH "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/..")
        if (NOT EXISTS "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/bin")
            set(QT_INSTALL_PATH "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/..")
        endif ()
    endif ()
    if (EXISTS "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/plugins/platforms/qwindows${DEBUG_SUFFIX}.dll")
        add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
                COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory
                "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>/plugins/platforms/")
        add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
                COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
                "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/plugins/platforms/qwindows${DEBUG_SUFFIX}.dll"
                "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>/plugins/platforms/")
    endif ()
    foreach (QT_LIB Core Gui Widgets)
        add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
                COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
                "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/bin/Qt6${QT_LIB}${DEBUG_SUFFIX}.dll"
                "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>")
    endforeach (QT_LIB)
endif ()
```

Nearly all of the blogs I've found told me to set the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`.
When I created a `Qt Widgets Executable` project in my `CLion 2023.1.4`, this had been already included in the auto-generated **CMakeList.txt**, but the error still exists.

Some blogs also mention the **32-bit platform** and the **64-bit-platform**, but all my Qt Build Kits I've installed are suitable for building 64-bit programs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you actually specify a some basic version constraint? For example `find_package(Qt6 6 COMPONENTS`  (I also wonder if `set(QT_VERSION 6.6.0)` is interfering with stuff here. I would remove that; the version should come defined from `find_package`, which should specify any constraints you need.

Comment: "Some blogs also mention the 32-bit platform and the 64-bit-platform, but all my Qt Build Kits I've installed are suitable for building 64-bit programs." - But your project is being built for 32-platform. This is what appendix "(64bit)" means: The referenced installation (`D:/Qt6/6.6.0/mingw_64/lib/cmake/Qt6/Qt6Config.cmake`) is for 64-bit platforms, which is incompatible with the platform against which the project is being configured.